# Was there a Blake’s 7 theme park ride for Stardrive?

Tags: blakes-7

My wife says I’m imagining this, but I’m sure when I was a child in the eighties I visited something like a stately home or theme park which had a ride based on the B7 episode Stardrive. It was in the uk but I’m not sure where as we were on holiday (so probably not East Anglia). There was a buggy thing that a group of us sat in and it drove around a quarry type landscape and explosions went off around us. Can’t remember if there were other riders on bikes driving around as well or if I’ve added that from seeing the episode again. Now I type it the idea that there were explosive charges seems a bit crazy, but this was pre health and safety time! The memory seems vivid but have I just imagined or dreamed the whole thing?!

Comment: Welcome to SciFi SE! ***Where*** specifically were you a child in the 1980s? Please edit your question to improve and attract better answers.

Comment: Safe to say it was the UK. Knowing what Blake's Seven is virtually guarantees it, and 'East Anglia' confirms it.

Comment: Around 1984,Lightwater Valley theme park in Ripon (in North Yorkshire,UK) had an amphibious buggy ride. It took about twelve passengers round a track in a quarry (or at least it looked quarry-like), up and down steep slopes and through deep puddles. There were no explosions though! Could this have been what you remember?

Comment: Could you not ask any family members where you went?

Comment: It could well be Lightwater Valley! My family don't remember where we went each year as we always went somewhere in the UK, but we definitely went to Yorkshire a few times. The 12 person buggy and quarry thing definitely fits my memory. It's possible that over the years I've conflated the trip with the actual episode, so there may not have been explosions! In the years I've been curious about this it only just occurred to me - if it wasn't Blakes 7 branded then pretending it was is the sort of thing Mum would have said to get me to go on it! Amazing. Thanks for solving this.

Comment: I have added this as an official answer. Many a great family day out was had at Lightwater Valley. It was a low tech place and so much fun!

Comment: @DJClayworth Naw: Blake's 7 was in syndication in the U.S. also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around 1984, Lightwater Valley theme park in Ripon (in North Yorkshire,UK) had an amphibious buggy ride. It took about twelve passengers round a track in a quarry (or at least it looked quarry-like), up and down steep slopes and through deep puddles. There were no explosions though! Could this have been what you remember? Maybe it was given a Blake's 7 theme at some point,
 though I don't remember it having a particular theme or franchise link when I went.